# How to edit Paypal API error messages?

Tags: magento, paypal, paypal-sandbox

In Magento when there's Paypal transaction error, it outputs a message like this:

> This transaction cannot be processed (#15005: Processor Decline)

Since the message doesn't originate in Magento, it cannot be updated via translate.csv.

What are options available for developer to make these messages more user friendly?

Comment: is there something like app/locale/en_US/Mage_Paypal.cvs? If you can find it, there are some error message translation in it. Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: There is, but the errors come from Paypal API, not from Magento.

Comment: The 15005 error means the bank declined it, which can happen for insufficient funds, a lost or stolen card, or etc. The bank doesn't provide more info, but those errors happen with some regularity. The other errors look valid in that they are "real" errors as reported by the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

This will not be easy but I think it's doable.

My guess would be to rewrite method
`_processPaypalApiError($exception)` in `Mage_Paypal_Controller_Express_Abstract`.

Since it's in an abstract class, you will have to rewrite one of the method (Express for example).

Also look at `_setApiProcessableErrors`

Comment: paypal_louis suggested Mage_Paypal.csv, if that works it's the better method